# How can I download a pdf file with Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I have an endpoint that returns a pdf file from a jersper report server and on frontend, I have an angular application that posts a parameter to that endpoint and returns the pdf file, so how can I download the file using that post request from the angular application.

When I use Postman to test the endpoint it shows the pdf file like its there to download like in the picture below
[image]

But when I run through my angular application I can't download it here my service and component code

report.service.ts

```
  public printReport(getData: any): Observable<any> {
let body = JSON.stringify(getData);
return this.http.post(`${this.configService.http_url}${this.endpoint_46}`, body, this.header)
  .pipe(
    map((resp: any) => { return resp; })
  );
}
```

and my report.component.ts

```
    public onSubmitForms(getData: any){
    let printData =  {
        report_name: 'Sample_Report',
        report_format:getData.report_format,
        filters:{
            start_date: this.datePipe.transform(getData.dateFrom, 'yyyy-MM-dd'),
            end_date: this.datePipe.transform(getData.dateTo, 'yyyy-MM-dd'),
        }
    }

    this.global.printReport(printData).subscribe(data => 
  this.downloadFile(data)),//console.log(data),
                 error => console.log('Error downloading the file.'),
                 () => console.info('OK');

  }

  downloadFile(data: any) {
    console.log(data)
    const blob = new Blob([data], { type: 'application/pdf' });
    const url= window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    window.open(url);
  }
}
```

but I don't get any file

Comment: Is it returning the appropriate headers? ie `content-type: application/pdf` ? that may have an impact...

Comment: it returning application/pdf

Comment: in your browser - in the devtools (F12 in most browsers) under network - do you see the .pdf url? and what return code does it say there? 404?

Comment: There is no .pdf file and i have 'accept' => 'application/octet-stream', on my headers

Comment: Does it work with another file type like .txt or .docx?

Comment: it doesn't work on the network Tab it shows like when i run on postman

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251319/discussion-between-ngatungaemily-and-josste).